# Changing Tabs width

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, view

The tabs in my app look like this.

[image: tabs]

Is there any way to have a single line for each title in the tabs.

This is the corresponding xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_TabPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"> . 
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change `app:tabMode="fixed"` to `app:tabMode="scrollable"`.

Comment: Thank you sir. It's all good now.

Comment: Do search before asking . Make up your Searching skills cause this question has already asked here . and its in documentations too .